# Is there any video lecture series on Graph Theory which uses "Introduction to Graph Theory" by Douglas West? as the text

Tags: reference-request, self-learning, resource-request, graph-theory

I am interested in learning graph theory, and from many resources I came to know that Douglas West's *Introduction to Graph Theory* is a good textbook. But since I am doing self-study, it is at times hard to understand the material without proper guidance.

So if anyone knows about any video lecture series on graph theory which uses the said text for reference, then it will be quite helpful to me. It would be like taking an actual course, getting input from the instructor, and then improvising on the learning thereafter by reading the text.

Being a self-learner, I am having a bit of difficulty in understanding a few concepts.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Not videos, so perhaps of little help. But here are daily lecture notes for a course at ETH using West's book: [ETH link](https://www.ti.inf.ethz.ch/ew/courses/GT04/index.html).

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke, if that course had video lectures as well it would have been just fantastic.. But thanks for the help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Canvas class for Dartmouth's Spring 2020 course in Graph Theory, Math 38, seems to be mostly open. According to the [syllabus](https://canvas.dartmouth.edu/courses/39351/assignments/syllabus), the course uses the 2nd edition of West's *Introduction to Graph Theory*.

> Course Description
> This course will cover the fundamental concepts of graph theory: simple graphs, digraphs, Eulerian and Hamiltonian graphs, trees, matchings, networks, paths and cycles, graph colorings, and planar graphs. Famous problems in graph theory include: the Minimum Connector Problem (building roads at minimum cost), the Marriage Problem (matching men and women into compatible pairs), the Assignment Problem (filling jobs with applicants), the Network Flow Problem (maximizing flow in a network), the Committee Scheduling Problem (using the fewest time slots), the Four Color Problem (coloring maps with four colors so that adjacent regions have different colors), and the Traveling Salesman Problem (visiting a list of cities minimizing the traveled distance).

If you navigate to the [Pages](https://canvas.dartmouth.edu/courses/39351/pages), you'll see Week 1, Week 2, etc. Behind each of those links is a wrap-up of the week's lectures.

The course ran for 10 weeks, 3 sessions per week. Each week seemed to have 8-12 prerecorded video lectures, most hosted on the [Dartmouth Mathematics Department](https://math.dartmouth.edu/%7Enadia/math38/) server, but a handful linked from YouTube. In addition, there was a live Zoom session that was recorded. The Zoom recordings appear to be inaccessible without a login, but notes taken during the live sessions are available. Also, each session has a PDF of the professor's lecture notes. Finally, if you want to work the weekly problem sets, those are available, too, but the solutions have been removed.

Available:

- About 100 prerecorded video lectures (10-15 minutes each)
- About 8 problem sets
- About 20 live Zoom notes

Not available:

- Recordings of live Zoom sessions
- Solutions to problem sets
- Quizzes, midterm, and final exam

Comment: wow, this a great resource. Thank you...