# Is there any video lecture series on (UG level) graph theory (might not be specific on any books) but the video/content quality is like that of MIT?

Tags: self-learning, resource-request, graph-theory

Previously I had asked a [question](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/19493/14166) about something similar, but more constrained. But now I ask something more general. I just got hold of the Linear Algebra by Prof Gilbert of MIT and they are just awesome. Especially the use of chalk board and explanations.

I am used to explanation in that type of environment. Can anyone provide me with such type of material on graph theory. Does MIT have one ?